# how to display an element of array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to display a element of array inside a loop.

```
result: {
  "success": true,
  "message": "Categories Found",
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "total": 5,
    "per_page": 15,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 5,
     "data": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "asset_id": 76,
            "parent_id": 12,
            "lft": 12,
            "rgt": 13,
            "level": 2,
            "path": "clothes/women",
            "extension": "com_content",
            "title": "Women",
            "alias": "women",
            "note": "",
            "description": "",
            "published": 1,
            "checked_out": 496,
            "checked_out_time": "2019-04-05 11:25:34",
            "access": 1,
            "params": "{\"category_layout\":\"\",\"image\":\"images\\/themeparrot\\/banner-category\\/banner.png\",\"image_alt\":\"women\"}",
            "metadesc": "",
            "metakey": "",
            "metadata": "{\"author\":\"\",\"robots\":\"\"}",
            "created_user_id": 496,
            "created_time": "2017-10-06 07:34:39",
            "modified_user_id": 496,
            "modified_time": "2017-12-05 12:39:35",
            "hits": 0,
            "language": "*",
            "version": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 9,
            "asset_id": 78,
            "parent_id": 12,
            "lft": 14,
            "rgt": 15,
            "level": 2,
            "path": "clothes/men",
            "extension": "com_content",
            "title": "Men",
            "alias": "men",
            "note": "",
            "description": "",
            "published": 1,
            "checked_out": 0,
            "checked_out_time": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "access": 1,
            "params": "{\"category_layout\":\"\",\"image\":\"images\\/themeparrot\\/banner-category\\/banner_02.png\",\"image_alt\":\"men\"}",
            "metadesc": "",
            "metakey": "",
            "metadata": "{\"author\":\"\",\"robots\":\"\"}",
            "created_user_id": 496,
            "created_time": "2017-10-06 07:42:58",
            "modified_user_id": 496,
            "modified_time": "2017-12-05 12:39:40",
            "hits": 0,
            "language": "*",
            "version": 1
          },
```

An above is a response of an Api. This is loop function, in that need to display a image under params.

and my ts:

```
displaycategory(){
    this.showLoader();
    this.categories.categorydisplay().then((result) => {
      console.log('result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
      this.loading.dismiss(); 
      this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      this.categorydata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data.data.data));

    }), (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6  *ngFor="let tms of categorydata;" (click)="test($event, tms.id)" >

  <ion-card *ngIf="tms.parent_id == 12">
      <img src="{{tms.params.image}}">
      <div class="card-title">{{tms.title}} </div>
      <div class="card-subtitle"></div>
    </ion-card>

  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

In this html i need to show an image.

Comment: What's all that horrible `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`? Please post `result` without stringifying it before. Should you receive the data like it is, fix the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with below from result json object directly

```
 this.categorydata = this.result.data.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your **base url** before the image path like this way.

**ts file** declare base url

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
 public baseurl='http://baseurl.xyz/';
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController
  ) {

  }
```

then just add this base url before your path

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6  *ngFor="let tms of categorydata;" (click)="test($event, tms.id)" >

  <ion-card *ngIf="tms.parent_id == 12">
      <img src="{{baseurl+tms.params.image}}">
      <div class="card-title">{{tms.title}} </div>
      <div class="card-subtitle"></div>
    </ion-card>

  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you should change your ts to process the result right:

- You are using `this.data.data.data` where it should be `this.data.data`.
- You should parse only the `params` field that is a string

```
displaycategory(){
    this.showLoader();
    this.categories.categorydisplay().then((result) => {
      console.log('result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
      this.loading.dismiss(); 
      this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      this.categorydata = this.data.data.map(({params, ...rest}) => ({...rest, params: JSON.parse(params)}));

    }), (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I think this way, it should work.

Remember in the next questions to detail the error you are receiving.